# How to use VLOOKUP - using pandas, I guess - with python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dataframe

I'm learning python and  I would like to populate one dataframe by getting data from another. If I use excel I would use VLOOKUP, although I know I can use pandas  with python, i don't now how. Basucally, I have two dataframes:

df1.csv

```
Time           07:03:52
EmployeeID     98766
EmployeeName   "John"

Time           08:03:52
EmployeeID     98765
EmployeeName   "Mary"
```

df2.csv

```
Time   EmployeeID   EmployeeName
```

I would like to create a third dataframe from `df2.csv` like this:

df3.csv

```
EmployeeName  EmployeeID   Time
John          98766        07:03:52
Mary          98765        08:03:52
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need first reshape to rows by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) + [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and then if need change ordering of columns use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv', names=['a','b'])
print (df1)
              a         b
0          Time  07:03:52
1    EmployeeID     98766
2  EmployeeName      Joao
3          Time  08:03:52
4    EmployeeID     98765
5  EmployeeName      Mary

#for columns names created from file2
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv')
c = df2.columns.str.strip().tolist()
print (c)
['EmployeeID', 'EmployeeName', 'Time']

#or defined in list
#c = ['Time', 'EmployeeID', 'EmployeeName']

g = df1.groupby('a').cumcount()
df1 = df1.set_index([g,'a'])['b'].unstack().reindex(columns=c)
print (df1)
a EmployeeID EmployeeName      Time
0      98766         Joao  07:03:52
1      98765         Mary  08:03:52
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! The only problem is that df3 is  like this:

   EmployeeID   EmployeeName      Time               EmployeeName   Time
0      98766       Joao                         07:03:52        NaN                      NaN
1      98765       Mary                         08:03:52        NaN                      NaN

Comment: Can you explain more creating `df3` from `df2` ? the best is ass some sample data to `df2` and add expected output to `df3`. Or `df2` have no values, only header?

Comment: Yes, `df2` has only header. Basically, I want to use the information of `df1`  to paste at the exact column of `df2`, creating a new file.csv (`df3`)

Comment: No , it  returns that:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_url.py", line 372, in <module>
    g = df.groupby('a').cumcount()
NameError: name 'df' is not defined

Comment: It returned:

`a EmployeeID   EmployeeName   Time
0      98766            NaN                 NaN
1      98765            NaN                 NaN`

I mean: its not getting the information from Employee Name and Time.

Comment: Are your data confidental?

Comment: Because problem seems in data. so is possible send me your file to my email in my profile?

Comment: thank you, I find problem. After read your `df2` there was trailing whitespaces in columns names, so need `str.strip` for remove them. Now it should working nice, please check it.

Comment: Hey jezrael, I think the best way to address it is asking a new question, so I did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48359925/how-to-use-pandas-to-read-a-line-from-a-csv-proceed-a-vlookup-action-and-save-t

Comment: And I add answer ;)