# How to use pandas to read a line from a csv, proceed a VLOOKUP action and save the results into another file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dataframe

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48357044/how-to-use-vlookup-using-pandas-i-guess-with-python?answertab=active#tab-top), I found how to use pandas to proceed VLOOKUPs.
So, as suggested by jezrael, I did this:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv', names=['a','b'])
print (df1)
              a         b
0          Time  07:03:52
1    EmployeeID     98766
2  EmployeeName      Joao
3          Time  08:03:52
4    EmployeeID     98765
5  EmployeeName      Mary

#for columns names created from file2
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv')
c = df2.columns.str.strip().tolist()
print (c)
['EmployeeID', 'EmployeeName', 'Time']

#or defined in list
#c = ['Time', 'EmployeeID', 'EmployeeName']

g = df1.groupby('a').cumcount()
df1 = df1.set_index([g,'a'])['b'].unstack().reindex(columns=c)
print (df1)
```

I Got this:

```
a EmployeeID EmployeeName      Time
0      98766         Joao  07:03:52
1      98765         Mary  08:03:52
```

Now, I would like to understand how I can get a .csv file that has all the information of `df1` in lines, instead of 2 columns, and transform it in a temporary file of 2 columns, so I can read it and proceed with the VLOOKUP to `df3`. As the example bellow:

Now, imagine that **df1.csv** and **df2.csv** have other values:

**df1.csv**

```
Symbol, A;Goal,1.07;Range,0.72 - 1.07;Return over time,15.91%;;
Symbol, B;Goal,1.06;Range,0.5 - 1.32;Return over time,9.91%;Maturity,5;Total,13.555
```

**df2.csv**

```
Return_over_time,Maturity,Symbol,Goal,Range,Total
```

I would like to get the same result as above, but getting the information from each line of `df1`. So I can have this result:

df3.csv

```
Symbol  Return_over_time   Goal   Range        Maturity   Total
A       15.91%             1.07   0.72 - 1.07
B       9.91%              1.06   0.5 - 1.32   5          13.555
```

Thanks!

Comment: This might be of interest for you https://michaeljsanders.com/2017/04/17/python-vlookup.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create DataFrame - `header=None` means no `csv` header:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv', sep=';',header=None)
```

Reshape to `Series` by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by regex `'\s*,\s*` means double zero or more whitespaces between comma:

```
df1 = df1.stack().str.split('\s*,\s*', expand=True)
print (df1)
                    0            1
0 0            Symbol            A
  1              Goal         1.07
  2             Range  0.72 - 1.07
  3  Return over time       15.91%
1 0            Symbol            B
  1              Goal         1.06
  2             Range   0.5 - 1.32
  3  Return over time        9.91%
  4          Maturity            5
```

Remove second level by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and add new level by 
[`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), last reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df1.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).set_index(0, append=True)[1].unstack()
print (df1)
0  Goal Maturity        Range Return over time Symbol   Total
0  1.07     None  0.72 - 1.07           15.91%      A    None
1  1.06        5   0.5 - 1.32            9.91%      B  13.555
```

Comment: i got: pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 2, saw 7

Comment: hmm, not missing last `;;` ?

Comment: Noup. Sent you the csv. Anyway, if I just do: 
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv', header=None) 
print(df1)
 -> I get: a lot of errors about pandas' libs:   File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2184, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:28765)
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 2, saw 7

Comment: Can you send me your data file? Because it should working nice.

Comment: Ok. I've sent you

Comment: I forget for separator is `sep=';'`